# Is `ink_env::ecdsa_recover` safe to use in production-ready contracts?

Tags: ink

We're running a private chain with substrate version `polkadot-v0.9.18`. Is it safe to use `ink_env::ecdsa_recover` for production contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet: The feature is still [flagged unstable](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts#unstable-interfaces) and can be changed in new versions of pallet-contracts if necessary. This will break already deployed contracts which is a big no-no for production chains. This is why all unstable features are guarded behind a cargo feature flag so that they are only used for development.

However, it is unlikely that this function will change when it is stabilized. You can start writing contracts against it knowing that some version of it will be available on production chains.

Comment: Tks for the information. Is it ok to use `k256` crate? Because we need to have a backup plan if ink! team decide to stabilize after we launched the contracts.

Comment: k256 should work. We use it inside the substrate runtime, too. However it could be that it makes to contract too big.

Comment: We will definitely have to check on that. One more thing: "Does contract size affect the gas fee?". As I understand, "automatic deposit collection” (https://www.parity.io/blog/ink-3-0-paritys-rust-based-language-gets-a-major-update) will only affect what storage users use, not the contract size?

FYI: We're running the solochain, as I know, contracts in parachains is a very complexed subject so we may want to skip the complexity of this if it concerns you.

Comment: Contracts are part of storage, too. So the deposit will be higher for bigger contracts when uploading them. Additionally, bigger contracts also execute slower (more code needs to be executed) and hence consume more gas.

Answer (score 2):

*Update*: we have covered `ecdsa_recover` and `ecdsa_to_eth_address` functions with tests and now have them stabilized. So the next **ink!** release is going to have them ready for production contracts. You can always go ahead and build your contract with cutting edge **ink!** crates taken from the *[master](https://github.com/paritytech/ink)* branch if you just can't wait for the next release.

Comment: Yes, this is great